# twitter and google login from two pages

Tags: php, url, redirect, twitter

I am working in a PHP language . I have made a app for twitter and google . Its working fine . I have two pages ie REGISTRATION.PHP and SIGN-IN.PHP  in which I have given the login for TWITTER and GOOGLE .

In registration.php , I am collecting the basic information and storing it in the database

In sign-in.php , first I am checking whether  user details are in the database or not ......if yes then the user can see his/her details .

The problem is I don't know from where the user is coming ie registration.php or sign-in.php because the I have created one app only and I have one callback url . So how can I find out from where the user is coming ?

**1)**  Can i give URL parameter in callback url ?

Comment: Yes you can. You can pass a optional parameter.

Comment: please can u explain me more .......

Comment: when a user clicks on the login for twitter , my app will ask the permission to authorize but if the same user comes next day then also my ask for the permission ........... i want to stop it , Is there any way to stop ? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your own callback url.
Just for differentiating with other social media you can use a optional parameter like below. Once twitter will return user to your website you can get that optional parameter.

for twitter: `http://xyz.com/registration.php?type=twitter`

Comment: when a user clicks on the login for twitter , my app will ask the permission to authorize but if the same user comes next day then also my ask for the permission ........... i want to stop it , Is there any way to stop ?

Comment: As per my knowldge Callback url is the optional URL that you pass in social media sites during authentication. where social media sites will return you after authentication.

Comment: Yes you can store the details that you get from the twitter after successfully authorization. And use that details next time when user comes to your website.

Comment: if leave the callback url blank , its shows me the error in my page and I am not saving any details in database so how will i use the deatils

Comment: like in google u can use this $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');     Is there any way for twitter also

Comment: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth     I have downloaded the twiiter code from this website

Comment: This might be useful for you [@inorganik Jamie](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3150)